# Quantile Regression and Independent Errors

Tags: econometrics, quantile-regression, endogeneity

I am struggling to understand two different quantile regression specifications and the assumptions of conditional quantile independence and full independence. In the first specification, suppose we have the location-scale model:
\begin{equation}
y_{i}=\beta_{0}+x_{i}^{'}\beta+(\delta_{0}+\delta_{1}x_{i}^{'})\epsilon_{i}
\end{equation}
So that $Var(\epsilon_{i}|x)$ depends on $x_{i}$. Our identification conditions in the linear quantile regression model restrict $Q_{\tau}(\epsilon_{i}|x_{i})=0$, so how is it possible in this model, that changes in $x_{i}$ can have any impact on any percentile of the conditional distribution?

In a more general, random coefficient model:
\begin{equation}
y_{i}=x_{i}^{'}\beta(\epsilon_{i}), \quad \epsilon_{i}\sim Unif(0,1),
\end{equation}
where we assume $\epsilon$ is independent from $x_{i}$. So how can there be any interesting marginal effects of the covariates on the conditional distribution if we assume full independence?

My conclusion is that when these independence assumptions are valid, quantile regression is useful only for its "robustness-to-outliers" property. When there is endogeneity, quantile regression becomes much more interesting, but requires different identification conditions such as those in IVQR (Chernozhukov and Hansen, 2005) or control functions (Lee, 2007 or Imbens and Newey, 2009) especially when a model such as the second equation represents a structural relationship between $y$ and $x$. Is this reasoning correct?